# How to make dynamic fields in zapier platform?

Tags: zapier, zapier-cli

I want to make dynamic fields in Zapier platform. If a user chooses "Yes", then 4-5 fields are displayed, otherwise not. 
I have seen this type of example in ZOHO CRM integration 
[where only 2 fields are shown at first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyN0F.png).

There are only 2 fields now. When we choose "standard" in the first field, many fields are shown/open.
[Here are all the fields that show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNVHe.png)

Similar to this, I want a field in which there are two options, "Yes" and "No".
If user select Yes, then 4-5 fields should open (otherwise not). The user can use the fields to send data.

Answer (score 1):

There's documentation about this process [here](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform/tree/master/packages/cli#customdynamic-fields) (copied below)

```js
const recipeFields = (z, bundle) => {
  const response = z.request('http://example.com/api/v2/fields.json');
  // json is is [{"key":"field_1"},{"key":"field_2"}]
  return response.then(res => res.json);
};

const App = {
  //...
  creates: {
    create_recipe: {
      //...
      operation: {
        // an array of objects is the simplest way
        inputFields: [
          {
            key: 'title',
            required: true,
            label: 'Title of Recipe',
            helpText: 'Name your recipe!'
          },
          {
            key: 'style',
            required: true,
            choices: { mexican: 'Mexican', italian: 'Italian' }
          },
          recipeFields // provide a function inline - we'll merge the results!
        ],
        perform: () => {}
      }
    }
  }
};
```

In your case, you'll replace the `style` field with your yes/no. The `recipeFields` function will have an `if` statement that checks the value of `bundle.inputData.style` and either returns more field objects or `[]`, depending if more fields should be shown.

Comment: Hello David,
I have done this code but doesn't got anything https://www.screencast.com/t/CzZxxsLN